# Is there an equivalent `mvn dependency:build-classpath` for gradle projects?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm looking for a command or a task that would achieve the equivalent output to maven `mvn dependency:build-classpath` for Gradle projects.

Here is some example output that maven produces:

```
/Users/test-user/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.4.3/mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:/Users/test-user/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.4.3/mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:/Users/test-user/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/bson/3.6.3/bson-3.6.3.jar:/Users/test-user/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar:/Users/test-user/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a built-in task which does the same thing, though I'm not positive. However, you could always create your own task which prints out the classpath as a path. Here's an example using the Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.register("buildClasspath") {
    val main by sourceSets
    doFirst {
        println(main.compileClasspath.asPath)
    }
}
```

***Note:** To print the runtime classpath use `main.runtimeClasspath`.*

You can then execute:

```
./gradlew buildClasspath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to see all the dependencies.

```
gradle -q dependencies
```

You can refer below the link.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies